# how to delete records out of table storage within a certain date range?

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-runbook

I'd like to be able to delete records out of table storage that have a `TimeStamp` between  11/15/2020 and 12/15/2020.

For example :

[image]

**How do we delete records out of table storage within a specified date range using powershell?**

Here's what I've tried:

```
$storageAccountName = "mystorageaccount"
$resourceGroup = "myresourcegroup"
$tableName = "FilesReceived"
$columnName = "Timestamp"
$value = "datetime'2021-09-15T00:00:00Z'"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context 

$storageTable = Get-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx
$cloudTable = ($storageTable).CloudTable

[string]$filter = `
  [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition($columnName,`
  [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::LessThan,$value)

# Get entity
$entityToDelete = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter

$entityToDelete | Remove-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable
```

However, when I inspect the contents of `$entityToDelete`, it is totally empty.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we delete records out of table storage within a specified date
> range?

Unlike relational databases where you would simply execute a delete query, in Table Storage you would first need to fetch the entities you would want to delete and then send requests to delete those entities.

To fetch the entities, you would need to do a query like `Timestamp ge datetime'2021-11-15T00:00:00Z' and Timestamp le '2021-12-15T00:00:00Z'`. You could do query projection and only fetch `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` attributes as only these two attributes are required for deletion.

Once you have fetched the entities, you can send a delete request for each entity separately or do an entity batch transaction to delete up to 100 entities in a single request.,

Comment: would love to know which delete command to use. i've downloaded the latest powershell version

Comment: i've updated the question and added the code i'm attempting to run

Comment: gaurav, are you there?

Comment: @AlexGordon - I ran your code and was able to successfully delete the data. Can you share the output of `$filter`? I hardcoded the query in my code. This is the code I used to fetch the entities: `$data = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter "Timestamp ge datetime'2010-09-15T00:00:00Z'" -Top 1 -SelectColumn "PartitionKey,RowKey"`.